# ios: Universal links not working on iOS 10

Tags: ios, xcode, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to integrate universal links in my iOS app. So whenever someone taps on `<myapp>.herokuapp.com/content` gets redirected directly to app. I followed [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Handoff/AdoptingHandoff/AdoptingHandoff.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014338-CH2-SW10) guide for setup. I did the following setup but cannot get it working. I also checked other threads on stackoverflow but none of them solved the issue.

- Added Associated Domains in Capabilities Tab on my app's target. Added two domains: `activitycontinuation:<myapp>.herokuapp.com` and `applinks:<myapp>.herokuapp.com`.
- In Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources added the file .entitlements.
- Got teamId from https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership
- On my website added a route for `apple-app-site-association` at `https://<myapp>.herokuapp.com/apple-app-site-association` which returns the following json:

  ```
  {
      "applinks": {
          "apps": [],
          "details": [
              {
                  "appID": "<teamId>.<bundleId>.dev",
                  "paths": [ "*" ]
              },
              {
                  "appID": "<teamId>.<bundleId>",
                  "paths": [ "*" ]
              }
          ]
      },
      "activitycontinuation": {
          "apps": [
              "<teamId>.<bundleId>.dev",
              "<teamId>.<bundleId>"
          ]
      }
  }
  ```
- Installed app from Xcode to iPhone 6s Plus (physical device) with bundle id `<bundleId>.dev` and copied link `https://<myapp>.herokuapp.com/content` to Notes but it opens in Safari.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed the issue. The problem was that I was testing with Debug configuration. When I tried with Release build everything is now working fine.

Comment: how to set release build ? Should we set some settings?

Comment: In Xcode Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme. Run tab > Build Configuration > Release.

Comment: I have the same error. @meteors did you add your domain like www.domainename.com or only domainename.com without www. ? Thanks

Comment: @JulienLevallois I added it as www.domainname.com.

Comment: @meteors, How did you test it ? Did it worked from link tap on email links , notes link or message link ? My apple-app-site-association is accessible and applinks are provided properly. But it is not working.

Comment: Yes I checked using Notes app.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a lot of issues that could be preventing your Universal Links from working here.

Here are some things to double-check:

- Is the AASA file properly named, and properly signed?
- Are you testing with a physical device? (some say Universal Links now work consistently in the simulator with iOS 10, but I'd still use a physical device)
- Are your device and provisioning certificates all error-free?
- Could the AASA file have failed to update when the app was first installed/launched due to an issue with network connectivity (I find that the AASA will fail to download if Charles Proxy is capturing traffic, for example)
- When testing, are you first pasting the link into Notes and then long-pressing on it? Are you seeing the "Open in App" menu option? If so, Universal Linking is working properly and has just been disabled on the device.

I would also recommend running through Alex Austen's super blog post on this topic, as doing so may help you spot the problem (here: https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9/).

Branch has a number of tools/resources for identifying Universal Linking issues. They are specifically intended for use with Branch links, but you may still find them helpful:

- AASA Validator: https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/
- Universal Link Validator: https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-linking-validator/guide/
- Universal Linking Troubleshooting Guide: https://support.branch.io/support/solutions/articles/6000153326-ios-universal-links-troubleshooting-guide

Comment: Hello @dwestgate
- I didn't sign the AASA file because it's mentioned that signed AASA files are only required if you support lesser than iOS 9.0. I'm serving the file with Content-Type application/json.

- Yes I'm testing on a physical device.
- My provisioning profile seem to be correct because I'm able to install a release build on my iPhone.

- I don't know that apple tries to download AASA file when I install the app. If so then I'll try to capture the request using Charles Proxy but currently I don't have it running.

Comment: - I installed app before writing to Notes and there is no Open App options available on long press.

Comment: Ohh why stackoverflow doesn't support markdown in comments?

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the "signed AASA files are only required if you support lesser than iOS 9.0" information, but that doesn't sound right at all. AASA files were introduced to support Universal Linking, and Universal Linking was only introduced with iOS 9. There is no scenario where you would need an AASA if using a version of iOS before 9. Sign your AASA file.

Comment: There are so many moving pieces that I also recommend testing configurations step-by-step. Maybe create a Branch account and configure a test app to work with Branch (llike https://github.com/BranchMetrics/ios-branch-deep-linking/tree/master/Branch-TestBed-Swift) - see whether the Branch-hosted AASA file looks and acts the same as your AASA file.

Comment: In the Apple docs link that I followed: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Handoff/AdoptingHandoff/AdoptingHandoff.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014338-CH2-SW10. In Web browser to native app handoff section, check the paragraph after Listing 2-8 and a note which specifies sending application/json for iOS 9 and above.

Comment: Okay I'll try creating a test branch application with current configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Paste your domain into this [link](https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com/) and check that it doesn't have issues

Comment: that link checks for Content-Type as `application/pkcs7-mime` whereas it is no longer required for iOS 9 and above.

Comment: So you are serving it with Content-Type application/json ?

Comment: Yes. Its mentioned here that you can serve with Content-Type application/json: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Handoff/AdoptingHandoff/AdoptingHandoff.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014338-CH2-SW10