# Universal Link for multiple targets

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios-universal-links

I have an application with mutiple targets, implicitly with multiple domains, for each target. I followed this tutorial

> -> https://www.raywenderlich.com/128948/universal-links-make-connection

and I tested it on

> -> https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com/

just getting always Your file must be served with the content type

> "application / pkcs7-mime"

although the domain is https. Where exactly do I get wrong? Plus, I basically want to open one application from another is possible with universal linking since there are 2 different applications with 2 different domains?

Comment: I think that is an old tutorial as the `apple-app-site-association` should have `application/json` MIME type with newer versions of iOS. See here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: You can also try this AASA Validator: http://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/

Comment: actually the validator is ok . 
Your domain is valid (valid DNS).
 Your file is served over HTTPS.
 Your server does not return error status codes greater than 400.
 Your file's 'content-type' header was found :)
 Your JSON is validated.

Comment: So does it work when you try to open a link with the associated domain? If the validation is passing and you have setup your app correctly, it should work.

Comment: what bothers me it s still opening in Safari, and when the Open tab pops-up on the menu to open in App, only then it triggers my app-delegate function... but i dont know how to do it permanently...i mean dont open in safari since i have the app installed

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the app from the device and then installing it again? Sometimes this can resolve issues such as the one you are seeing.

Comment: Did that, also deleted the history of safari...still preferring to open in the browser instead of app...only if i click on the open button from safari it will trigger my app

Comment: Hmmm, i'm a bit stuck then and don't know what to suggest. On this similar question, they found that changing the build configuration helped. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42469232/ios-universal-links-not-working-on-ios-10?rq=1

Comment: I ll see where the problem comes from. Thanks btw

Comment: Paste a Universal Link in youre notes app. Long press on the link, then choose open in app. From then on your app should open if a universal link is clicked

Comment: Did you figure out how to have different universal links for multiple targets?